# Corsair dominator ram overheating?

Tags: memory, cooling

I am having overheating issues with my PC, this obviously occurs when it is under load (such as playing games).
The GPU and CPU heat up to about 87 degrees celcius.
However I have 4gb of [Corsair Dominator RAM](http://www.corsair.com/_datasheets/twin2x2048-8500c5d.pdf) (pdf) and it seems to be reaching 100 degrees as the machine overheats.
This model of ram comes with heatsinks attached and a small set of 3 fans that mount on top of the RAM modules.  The memory is not overclocked and is running at 800mhz.l

I am using RivaTuner and simply examining the temperatures after the machine has frozen.  Could someone also perhaps recommend a good temperature diagnostic tool?

Is 100 degrees C normal? What can I do to stop overheating?

Comment: Check your air flow.  It should go IN the front and OUT the back of the case.  Also make sure there is room around the case so the front intakes are not sucking in hot air.

Comment: Are you overclocking?  85+ is normal for a GPU, but that is very hot for a CPU, and your ram should not be anywhere near that temperature.  Either the system is clocked far too high, or something has gone wrong cooling-wise.  I suggest checking to make sure all the fans work and are oriented correctly, and that there are no blockages.

Comment: I'm not overclocking at all, I have quite a big case with numerous fans (Antec 1200), I'm going to install a new SSD soon so I might re-adjust the cables to ensure better airflow then.

Comment: Airflow is good, with the side of the case off, I felt the components to see how hot they were when the machine froze, none of them are too hot to touch.  Perhaps rivatuner is misreporting the temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem due to my computer freezing turned out to be my videocard.
I have been running this new video card for a few months and have had no problems.
I have cable tied down all of my cabling inside the box to make sure it has better airflow, this seems to have improved things a bit.
I suspect the temperature is not being reported correctly.